# React Native child views not responding to touches or clicks after adding it to the native UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, uigesturerecognizer, flipview

I have successfully integrated native objective c library `ITRFlipper` with react- native views and its flipping animation working but `subviews` or `childviews` inside each react native views not responding to click or touches

I have tried `[view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]`;
Then too no response.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds that you're not successful :D.   Do you have a github repo that anyone can look at?

Comment: i have successfully flipped react native views you can have a look [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzC3mSimbwc0aGtpOXZ3aEVVV3M/view)

Comment: Thanks @JayGarcia for helping  ! finally i have solved the issue and its woking fine i was doing silly mistake that view should be inside the RCTRootContentView